# Access AsyncStorage from native code

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need to persist data in local storage using AsyncStorage from JS code.

I would like to know if there is a way to access data stored from AsyncStorage from native code (Objective-C or Java).

Thanks!

Comment: If you/anyone are still looking for this. Check my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164887/can-i-access-data-stored-in-react-natives-asyncstorage-from-java-layer/47551790#47551790

Answer (score 2):

If you import `RCTAsyncLocalStorage.h`, you can call `_getValueForKey`: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTAsyncLocalStorage.m#L266

Comment: Because `_getValueForKey` is a private method, I tried to call:     `[asyncLocalStorage multiGet:@[@"USER_MESSENGER_SESSION"] callback:^(NSArray *response){
        if ([response count] > 0) {
            NSDictionary *userMessengerSession = response[0];
            if (userMessengerSession) {
                [[SinchClientManager sharedManager].sinchService logInUserWithId:userMessengerSession[@"user"][@"id"]];
            }
        }
    }];` But I had a SIGABRT

Comment: @draw I got it going like this, but it's hacky at best: `RCTAsyncLocalStorage *asyncLocalStorage = [[RCTAsyncLocalStorage alloc] init];
  dispatch_async([asyncLocalStorage methodQueue], ^{
    [asyncLocalStorage _ensureSetup];
    
    NSDictionary *err = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    NSString* val = [asyncLocalStorage _getValueForKey:@"@foobar" errorOut:&err];
    if (err) {
      
    }
  });`