# Can I access data stored in React Native's AsyncStorage from java layer?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am storing few user preferences in React Native using `AsyncStorage`. Now, I need to get those preference from a background service. I can't access `AsyncStorage` from the Java layer. Is there a way to do it?

In iOS, We can import `RCTAsyncLocalStorage.h` and call `_getValueForKey`. But, I can't find a way to do it in Android.

Answer (score 7):

I have following code which does the job.

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.storage.AsyncLocalStorageUtil;
import com.facebook.react.modules.storage.ReactDatabaseSupplier;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
.....
.....


SQLiteDatabase readableDatabase = null;
readableDatabase = ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).getReadableDatabase();
 if (readableDatabase != null) {
    String impl = AsyncLocalStorageUtil.getItemImpl(readableDatabase, "myTableName");
    Log.d(TAG, "impl: " + impl);
  }

====================
and to delete the DB
=====================
SQLiteDatabase database = ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(getContext()).getWritableDatabase();
database.delete(CATALYST_LOCAL_STORAGE, null, null);
```

Comment: I'm using ```redux-persist```, do you have any idea of how can I know the name of ```myTableName```

Comment: @Pablo I know this is an old post. but if anyone needs to read redux-persist database using this method, database name is "catalystLocalStorage" and key is "persist:root" assuming key name given as root when configuring redux-persist.

Comment: @Pablo "myTableName" is the table name I had defined and created from ReactNative by doing AsyncStorage.setItem("myTableName", JSON.stringify(obj)); 
and obj here is just a object which has key value pairs. And to access this table created at JS layer, I use above method i mentioned which still works.

Comment: Can you highlight what imports are required for this on the Android side?

Comment: @MuhammadRiyaz, thanks for posting this.
Is a any way to clear the database or value ?

Comment: @AnkitJayaprakash please check the answer I have added delete db snippet which I use.

Comment: @AmoghJahagirdar sorry for late reply. Check out the answer I have updated with imports.

Comment: @AmoghJahagirdar I used the same, but it says No table found with that name. But am able to read the database with that same table name.
So I this way
``ReactDatabaseSupplier readableDatabase = ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(context);
                    readableDatabase.clearAndCloseDatabase();``

Answer (score 6):

I tried to use the `AsyncStorage` from the java layer. But, I couldn't. So, I built a React Native plugin to access Android's Native `SharedPreferences` from the javascript layer. I have published it in the github (https://github.com/sriraman/react-native-shared-preferences)

Now I'm using this `SharedPreferences` from both `Java` and `React Native` layer.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use directly the `ReactDatabaseSupplier` class (my app doesn't use `Rocksdb` so I can be quite sure that the SQLite DB is always used as storage (and, I guess it will always prefer the SQLite database over local storage))

The database is a simple key-value DB (two columns, `key` and `value`), with a table name 'catalystLocalStorage' (you can try to read the `ReactDatabaseSupplier#TABLE_NAME` but it's protected, you can try using reflection, but I'm not sure it's worth the troubles)

```
Cursor catalystLocalStorage = null;
SQLiteDatabase readableDatabase = null;

try {
  readableDatabase = ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).getReadableDatabase();
  catalystLocalStorage = readableDatabase.query("catalystLocalStorage", new String[]{"value"}, "key = ?", new String[] { "keyName" }, null, null, null);
  final String value = catalystLocalStorage.getString(catalystLocalStorage.getColumnIndex("value"));
  [...]
} finally { 
  if (catalystLocalStorage != null) {
    catalystLocalStorage.close();
  }

  if (readableDatabase != null) {
    readableDatabase.close();
  }
}
```

It works to me, not sure how future-proof it can be

Answer (score 1):

Use react-native-default-preference. Its way better than react-native-shared-preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
React native
You need to create method in React native where you return values.
Native
Use PackagesModule Class Provided by facebook for access React-native method from Native
using this can able to access AsyncStorage

[Android Native Modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android)